# Creating SQLite DB in Android From Script

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to use some kind of ddl script in SQLiteHelper to create database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I usually have a main DB class in my application that encapsulates an inner class that derives from SQLiteOpenHelper.  In the onCreate, you get a SQLiteDatabase instance as a parameter.  Call `db.execSQL(String)` with the appropriate script(s) to create your tables and populate them.

Comment: Well it sounds I still have to convert my ddl to string with my hands(I was hoping that there is something like runScript method).

As I understood to upgrade I have to increment db version and in onUpgrade() method exec script which will include commands for deleting old tables, creating few new tables, and inserting some default data, am I right?

Comment: Yeah...that's correct.  What format is your DDL in?  You don't have to convert your scripts to java strings by typing them out manually.  You can load your scripts to text and parse them in code.

Comment: _You don't have to convert your scripts to java strings by typing them out manually._ I knew that (= Thanks for response.